# DELETE not working in the Laravel Datatable

Tags: php, laravel, yajra-datatable

I am working with Laravel Datatable and I have stuck in one point. Below code for delete the entry in the TagManagement model. But it isn't delete the entry and worse thing is it didn't show any error. Can anybody find the error in below code?

**view**

```
 $(document.body).on("click",".remove-tag", function () {

        var tag_id = $(this).data('id');
        showConfirm("DELETE", "Do you want to delete this Tag ?","deleteTag("+tag_id+")");
    });

    function deleteTag(id){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '{!! url('delete-tag') !!}',
            data: {tag_id: id},
            success: function (data) {
                    if (data == "SUCCESS") {
                        $('[data-id="' + id + '"]').closest('tr').remove();
                        showAlert("SUCCESS","Delete Tag successful");
                    }
                }, error: function (data) {

                    showAlert("FAIL","Delete Tag fail");
                }

        });
    }
        var tag_id = $(this).data('id');
        showConfirm("DELETE", "Do you want to delete this Tag ?","deleteTag("+tag_id+")");
    });

    function deleteTag(id){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '{!! url('delete-tag') !!}',
            data: {tag_id: id},
            success: function (data) {
                    if (data == "SUCCESS") {
                        $('[data-id="' + id + '"]').closest('tr').remove();
                        showAlert("SUCCESS","Delete Tag successful");
                    }
                }, error: function (data) {

                    showAlert("FAIL","Delete Tag fail");
                }

        });
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public function destroy($id)
    {

        $tagManagement = TagManagement::find($id);
        $deleted = $tagManagement->delete();

        if ($deleted) {
            return "SUCCESS";
        } else {
            return "FAIL";
        }
    }
```

```
public function loadTags()
{

    $Tags = TagManagement::all();

    return DataTables::of($Tags)
        ->addColumn('action', function ($tag) {
            return '<a href="' . url('/tags/' . $tag->id . '/edit') . '" class="btn btn-default edit_btn_styles" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <button type="button" data-id="' . $tag->id . '" class="btn btn-default remove-tag remove-btn" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>';
        })
        ->rawColumns(['action'])
        ->make(true);
}
```

}

```
**Route**
```

**Route::get('/delete-tag', 'AdminPanel\TagController@destroy');**

Comment: have you checked the value of $id inside destroy method? Also let me know whether entry is deleted from db or not?

Comment: It isn't deleted from **DB**.  Yes I have checked. It saw nothing.

Comment: first print your qurey and exicute in console . it will make sure the right query is excuting . or your could simply use DB:table('table name')->where('id', $id))->delete()

Answer (score 1):

Your route and controller method don't seem to correspond. First of all, it is better to use the "delete" HTTP request method for delete actions, but this is not what is causing your problem.

You defined your route as `/delete-tag` but in your controller you expect an `$id` as a parameter to your `destroy` method. In order for that to work you would need to have the route like this `/delete-tag/{id}` and construct the URL for your ajax call correspondingly on the frontend. I'm surprised you don't get the `Missing argument 1 for App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::{closure}()` exception for malforming your request this way.

[Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#route-parameters) explains very well how to define routes with parameters.

It would be helpful if you included Laravel version in your question.

Here is how it should work:

Route definition

```
Route::delete('/delete-tag/{id}', 'AdminPanel\TagController@destroy')->name('delete-tag');
```

JS function

```
function deleteTag(id){
        let route = '{!! route('delete-tag', ['id' => '%id%']) !!}';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: route.replace('%id%', id);,
            data: {_method: 'delete'},
            success: function (data) {
                    if (data == "SUCCESS") {
                        $('[data-id="' + id + '"]').closest('tr').remove();
                        showAlert("SUCCESS","Delete Tag successful");
                    }
                }, error: function (data) {

                    showAlert("FAIL","Delete Tag fail");
                }

        });
    }
```

Comment: Just edited to include a working version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

It is not your Datatable problem, you missed some code, you did not define `route` & `jQuery function` properly, your `destroy($id)` function received a parameter but you do not receive any  parameter in your `route` & you not send `_token` in your ajax action you need to send `_token`

Check My code I am edited your code.

```
//Change your Route
Route::get('delete-tag/{id}', 'AdminPanel\TagController@destroy')->name('deleteTag');

//Change your function
function deleteTag(id){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url:'{{ route('deleteTag', '') }}/'+id,
        data: {_token: '{{csrf_token()}}'},
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == "SUCCESS") {
                $('[data-id="' + id + '"]').closest('tr').remove();
                showAlert("SUCCESS","Delete Tag successful");
            }
        }, error: function (data) {

            showAlert("FAIL","Delete Tag fail");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Now it is working but instead of  **SUCCESS","Delete Tag successful**  it saw  **FAIL, Delete  Tag fail**.